# Right time to ask for extension of contract

Tags: united-kingdom, contractors

I am a contractor and it is coming to a end in a month but there are chances to getting it extended or contract to permanent. When is the best time to ask the manager? I do have deliverables, should I ask then or ask the recruiter who put me here as he is in same building. If I get extended I would also want to ask for a new rate. This is to meet costs like what other companies offer such as child voucher (tax free money for child education) and travelling cost.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere to meet cost like what other companies offer such as child voucher (tax free money for child education) and travelling cost.

Comment: How do I put in the offer in sweet words so they might not cut me off and rather decline to raise my rate,

Comment: May bet better fit in freelancing.se

Answer (score 3):

> When is the best time to ask the manager?

Since you are a month away from the end of your contract, **the time to ask is now.**

That way, you'll get a sense of the possibility of being extended or not with sufficient time to start looking for your next gig if the answer is no.

Comment: I do have my deadline, so they can see my work. Then It will be better position for me to ask? as they haven't seen my work yet or maybe but I am not aware of it. As my manager works with me on my git braches he study my code and seems fine with it and what is the output.

Comment: contract was 3 months, as i was struggling to find work. I joined it.

Comment: that is where it is strange, my con started on aug13, ends of 13 oct. which makes 2 months. The senior management might have tabs on my progress but none that I am aware of being rasied.

Comment: @MisterPositive my main concern is education for my child and that is why I wanna talk about it as many companies give u child vouchers

Comment: @cookieMonster do you have anything to show for 2 months of work?  If so, why not ask?  if not, I would just *hope* they extend you.

Comment: @MisterPositive  yes they gonna see. I am due to show them and move onto next project which is already in pipeline.

Comment: update: they reviewed my work and really happy with it.

Comment: updated, I been offered perm position.

Answer (score 1):

> should I ask then or ask the recruiter who put me here as he is in
>   same building.

Recruiters/Contractor managers are pointless unless they have a job which has a budget and are managing that.  Most are just check cutting groups.  If your manager and/or his technical team is evaluating your work then that's who you need to keep happy.

Your manager's budget/needs will determine whether or not you have a job, recruiters and contract managers are just the messengers for that news.

**After you've proven your worth to whomever, ask if they have more work for you.**.  You're in a much better position to know when that is than we are, and it's not the same as being done.

As for getting a raise or more benefits, if you're not working for your manager directly then you're probably a contractor and that's a good conversation to have with them.  Contracting companies normally make more money if you make more money, so collect reasons why they can ask your manager for more and tell them.